# Windows issues : Access Network Drive

Tags: windows-7, dns, network-shares, windows-domain, network-drive

Here is my problem:
I can not access a network drive from my pc under windows 7.
The PC and my profil are in a domain.
When I connect with the same profile on a TSE, my network drive works.
When I connect to the same PC with another similar profile, the network drive works.

Do you have an idea of ​​the problem? it seems odd that my profile works without any problems in TSE and encounter a problem on my PC.

Comment: You will need to clarify what TSE is.

Comment: Do you mean Windows Terminal Server Edition? Also, have you contacted technical support for your domain for this issue?

Comment: Yest , TSE for Terminal Server Edition.

When I use the adress IP , it's work but not with the servername. ( ping servname  work).